# Mozart becomes a rock star

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

Mozart is brought back from the dead, or recreated somehow, I no longer recall which. The man who brings him to the present expects Mozart to compose music in the same eighteenth-century style as before. But that isn't the nature of Mozart, who in life was very much a creature of his time, and ambitious for fame. To his recreator's disappointment, Mozart evades control and becomes a rock star.

This is not Ron Pruitt's "Mozart in the 21st Century", a similar story with a happier ending (https://www.storystar.com/story/3504/ron-pruitt/fiction/science-fiction-2).

I am not sure when I first read this story in an English-language anthology. Sometime in the last fifty years!

Comment: Sounds some what like a scene in "Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure"...

Comment: Ye-e-es.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8UGAbAPPkk
But, no.

Comment: @user14111 Post it as an answer.  I showed up here to do that, but you got it first.  "Watch the Earth turn black beneath the wheels of my Harley."

Comment: Thanks, user14111, but "Mozart in Mirrorshades" takes place in 1775 in an alternate timeline. In that story, Mozart is not recreated, he is still alive. True -- as a rock star. It seems to be a popular idea that a modern Mozart would adapt easily to a new environment, and having read Hildesheimer's 1977 biography _Mozart_, I have to agree. The movie _Amadeus_ (1984) played loose and fast with history, but Tom Hulce nailed Mozart's frothy character (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z20dhgfP9VA).

Comment: I remember this story, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't Mozart but an earlier and much lesser composer - who, when reviewing what had happened in music since his death, was bowled over by the genius of Mozart. But he then went on to become a rock star, since his music was the rock of his generation. In fact, possibly the story identified in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/story-identification-composer-brought-from-the-past-to-the-future).

Comment: Daniel Roseman, you are right, it _was_ Pergolesi, not Mozart. You guys are good!

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron is it a duplicate of the Pergolesi question: [Story Identification: composer brought from the past to the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/story-identification-composer-brought-from-the-past-to-the-future)? If so I'll mark it as a duplicate. Silverberg's story *Gianni* does mention Mozart a lot so it's understandable why you'd have remembered Mozart in the story.

Comment: Yes, it is "Gianni" by Robert Silverberg, published in 1982. I'm still not sure when or where I read it, but that is definitely the right one. Thank you all for a stimulating discussion!

Comment: My first thought was "Mixed Doubles" by Daniel da Cruz (pub 1989).  "A university student uses a time machine to kidnap Schubert from his deathbed. He brings the master to the present and cures him with modern medicie, then exploits his talents to advance his own career."