# Looking for a time travel story in which Mozart is brought to the future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This is the plot from a short story as I remember it.  It was not a video or movie.

People in the future figure out how to bring people from the past to the future.  They grab Mozart from his deathbed and  "cure" him.  He discovers rock music, makes great music, but becomes a head case, ODs and on his death bed people from the further future "rescue" him.

Very similar to this story: [Story Identification: composer brought from the past to the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/story-identification-composer-brought-from-the-past-to-the-future), but not the same.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_Mirrorshades?

Comment: The accepted answer to your linked question is *"Gianni"* by Robert Silverberg, not *"Mozart in Mirroshades"* by Bruce Sterling.

Comment: Are you sure it was Mozart and not Schubert? https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/daniel-da-cruz/mixed-doubles.htm

Comment: @Valorum, my bad.  Sorry.  You are right.  They are different stories.

Comment: Pretty sure it was mozart.

Comment: I was also sure it was Daniel da Cruz's "Mixed Doubles" until you mentioned when he was  grabbed a second time Further into the future to cure him from his OD Death bed. Its been a long time since I read the book, but am pretty sure that does not happen in Mixed Doubles.

Comment: There is a novella called [But I'm Not the Only One](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1111151) by Chris Pierson in which many musicians (not just Mozart) are brought forward in time from just before their death. But the main character is _John Lennon_, and it doesn't have Mozart being "rescued" a second time.

Comment: @valorum Pretty sure [you got it on the first try](https://www.williamflew.com/omni84b.html).

Comment: @Spencer - OP says that it's not

Comment: @Valorum I don't see that. Were some comments deleted? "They are different stories" doesn't sound like it refers to Mozart in Mirrorshades.

Answer (score -3):

[*Bill & Ted Face the Music*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_%26_Ted%27s_Excellent_Adventure) features time travelers persuading Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart (not on his deathbed) to join them in the future, and Wolfie shreds with Hendrix in contemporary music:

And later, playing keyboards, joins Luis Armstrong, Bill & Ted, and others in a rock concert:

If *B&TFtM* is *not* your story it at least deserves an honorable mention. :D

Comment: Funny, but OP explicitly states that they're not looking for a film. And other than the brief presence of a time-traveling Mozart, none of the other plot elements match either

Comment: @Valorum You could have ended your comment with a period after the first word. :)

Comment: @Lexible sorry, I added the "short story" after your answer.  Funny reference for sure!